# How do I parse a line thorugh a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, svn, bash-scripting

I am very new to shell scripting I had a small query regarding the file parsing.

So, here's what I am trying to do:
I run an svn merge command, and genaratea conflict file 
my  conflict file is stored as conflicts.txt

What I want to do is read this file line by line 
and parse one line to match against some keywords.

For example one of the line in files look like this:
`C Client/Game/src/test/test.php`

Now I want to parse this line and search for the keyword `test`, in case I find it I want to do some action on it, for example aborting with exit status 2, 3, etc..

for example i want to iterate throught a text file called "FILENAME" which looks like this

`30 '!' C Client/test.js`

`31 '!' C Client/test2.js`

`32 '!' C Client/test3.js`
`

what i am doing is catting the file using the while loop and cat commnad

`cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
echo $LINE
done`

here i am just printing the line , i want to know how can i search for a keyworkd in the line and if i find that keyword how can i do some action on it like exiting with status 1

Can you please suggest some way to do this..

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but as it sounds, everything you need is already there. Check out the tool grep.

Comment: PLease include some specific examples. Show us your input file and your expected output. Do you have one keyword or many?

Comment: @terdon i have edited my question

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this, depending on your needs.

1. Simply print all lines containing the keyword `test`:

   ```
   grep test file.txt
   ```
2. The same but for many keywords. Create a file that has all the keywords, one per line and run

   ```
   grep -f keywords.txt file.txt
   ```
3. Process a file line by line, exit if the line is found

   ```
   while read line; do echo $line | grep test && break; done < file.txt
   ```
4. Exit with status 1 if the line matches. Unfortunately,if I remember correctly (not 100% sure), bash only allows you to set return values in functions. So, to get an exit status you need to use something else. Perl for example:

   ```
   perl -ne '/test/ && exit(1)' file.txt
   ```
5. Though you can't set an exit value, you can still do something similar with bash. The exit value of the last command run is always saved as `$?` in bash, that means you can test the value of `$?` and act accordingly:

   ```
   while read line; do let c++; echo $line | grep test >/dev/null; 
     if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then echo Match for line $c : $line;
     else echo No match for line $c; fi  
   done < file.txt
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is not to parse file line-by-line at all.

```
grep -q 'keyphrase' filename && exit <exitcode>
```

Comment: Don't work as root in the shell just to grep a string from a file.

Comment: I don't deal with formatting yet :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ function some_action { 
    echo found keyword
}

$ if grep -q -m1 -e 'test3' < input;
  then 
      some_action
  fi
found keyword
```

grep options:

- -q: quiet; don't print matches
- -m1: exit after one match
- -e: expression (keyword)

e.g:

```
$ grep . input
30 '!' C Client/test.js
31 '!' C Client/test2.js
32 '!' C Client/test3.js

$ if grep -q -m1 -e 'test3' < input; then some_action ; fi
found keyword
```